# Is there a way to search a document for a start-date and end-date time interval and send alert notifications using reverse query in Marklogic?

Tags: marklogic

How do you search a document for a time interval that can be used as a `cts:word` query in my Rule? My document contains a `start-date` and `end-date`. My criteria for search would be a 'date' parameter that should fall within this time interval.  If it does then I fire off an alert.

Currently this is my 'Rule' (already created config and action.)

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";  
declare namespace alert = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/alert";  
import module "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/alert" at "/MarkLogic/alert.xqy";  

let $rule := alert:make-rule(  
     "rule-TimeInterval",  
     "Rule for alerts on time interval.",  
     0,  
     cts:word-query(("Dog","Cat", "timestamp"),("distance-weight=10")),  
     "action-TimeInterval",  
     <alert:options/> )  
return alert:rule-insert("config-TimeInterval", $rule)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can construct any query that would match the desired documents at search time, and embed that in your rule. The reverse-query is used at document insert time, to figure out which rules match the new document.

In your case it sounds like you are looking for `(Dog OR Cat OR timestamp) AND (start-date LE '2018-02-28') AND (end-date GE '2018-02-28')`. That comes down to some kind of cts:query like this:

```
cts:and-query((
  cts:word-query(("Dog","Cat", "timestamp"),("distance-weight=10")),
  cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("start-date"), "<=", xs:date('2018-02-28')),
  cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("end-date"), ">=", xs:date('2018-02-28'))
))
```

You can replace `'2018-02-28'` with your desired value, but bear in mind it is not dynamic. You'll need a new rule for each different date you would like to alert on.

HTH!

Comment: Thank you.  I will try that.  Also how do i make ("Dog", "Cat") an AND and not OR in mt cts:word-query ?  Thanks again.

Comment: Just use two word-queries inside the and-query

Comment: Also note that you'll need to set up range indexes on `start-date` and `end-date`.